# Rules of Inference : Showing that we can conclude $\exists xP(x) \lor \exists xQ(x)$ from $\exists x( P(x) \lor Q(x))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

From my discrete mathematics class, we are given an exercise, where one of the question is we have to prove that we can conclude $\exists xP(x) \lor \exists xQ(x)$ from $\exists x( P(x) \lor Q(x))$ using only rules of inference. Some of my fellow students think that we can do that by first using existential instantiation so $\exists x( P(x) \lor Q(x))$ become $P(c) \lor Q(c)$ for a specific element $c$ in domain $x$, and then existential generalization it, but to $\exists xP(x) \lor \exists xQ(x)$. Is it right? And if so, why? I can't understand why it become $\exists xP(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)$ instead of $\exists x( P(x) \lor Q(x))$ again.

Comment: Well, yes, if you immediately follow existential elimination with existential introduction, you are going to end up back where you started, so some steps need to be inserted in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on exactly what inference rules you have to work with, but if you have something that formalizes a 'proof by cases', then from $P(c) \lor Q(c)$ you can infer $\exists x\ P(x)$ ( and thus $\exists x \ P(x) \lor \exists x \ Q(x)$ from the $P(c)$ case, and $\exists x \ Q(x)$ (and thus again $\exists x \ P(x) \lor \exists x \ Q(x)$) from the $Q(c)$ case.

Here is a formal proof to this effect created in the Fitch system:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Basically they are relying on $\exists x~(Sx\vee T)\iff (\exists x~Sx)\vee T$ holding if $x$ is not occuring free within $T$.

$\begin{array}{l|l:l}1 & \exists x ~(Px \vee Qx) & \text{Assume/Premise}
\\ 2 & \quad Pc\vee Qc & \text{Existential Instantiation/Elimination}
\\ 3 & \quad \exists x~(Px \vee Qc) & \text{Existential Generalisation}
\\ 4 & \quad (\exists x~Px)\vee Qc & \text{Distribution}
\\ 5 & \exists x~((\exists x~Px)\vee Qx) & \text{Existential Generalisation}
\\ 6 & (\exists x~Px)\vee (\exists x~Qx) & \text{Distribution}
\\ \Box & 
\end{array}$

---

If you don't wish to use distribution, then use Disjunctive Syllogism .

$\begin{array}{l|l:l}1 & \exists x ~(Px \vee Qx) & \text{Assume/Premise}
\\ 2 & \quad Pc\vee Qc & \text{Existential Instantiation/Elimination}
\\ 3 & \qquad Pc & \text{Assume}
\\ 4 & \qquad \exists x~Px & \text{Existential Generalisation/Introduction}
\\ 5 & \quad Pc\to \exists x~Px & \text{Conditional Introduction / Discharge Assumption}
\\ 6 & \quad Qc\to \exists x~Qx & \text{Similarly}
\\ 7 & \exists x~Px~\vee~\exists x~Qx & \text{Disjunctive Syllogism/Elimination}
\\ \Box & 
\end{array}$

---